# How to bind NavigateUrl property of Hyperlink dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my aspx page I have used a HyperLink control. In Navigate property I am trying to concat a string url and a query string value. while rendering the html code i don't see any navigation value in there. So I can not navigate with my generated link in aspx page. The code is given bellow:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkRecord" runat="server" Text="Show number of records"
  NavigateUrl='<%#String.Concat("~/ShowTables.aspx?ShowNumberOfRecords=Y&proj="
                 ,Request.QueryString["proj"]) %>' />
```

But when the html renders in page I found the following code

```
<a id="linkRecord">Show number of records</a>
```

Can anyone tell me where i have done wrong.

Thanks

Comment: You need to call `linkRecord.DataBind()` at some point (e.g., in `Render`) to execute the code in a `<%# ... %>` data-binding expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont try to bind a server control like that, do it in the code behind.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="linkRecord" runat="server" Text="Show number of records" />
```

Now in your page load put:

```
linkRecord.NavigateUrl=String.Concat("~/ShowTables.aspx?ShowNumberOfRecords=Y&proj=", Request.QueryString["proj"]);
```